# Is it possible to change display and store language in Windows Phone?

Tags: store, language-setting

Currently I reside in Russia and I am thinking about purchasing a WP smartphone.  I noticed that when I log in to the Microsoft App store through the web interface it's only allowing me to see it in Russian if my location is set to Russia but my Live account default locale is en-US.

Is this only the case with the web interface? Is it possible to switch the system and store languages on the WP device itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [change the Region and Language](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-change-display-language-windows-phone-8) in your phone's settings.

You can also view the app store for another region online by going to http://www.windowsphone.com/[LOCALE]/store .

For example:

- United States (EN-US) Store: www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store
- Russia (RU-RU) Store: www.windowsphone.com/ru-ru/store
- British (EN-GB) Store: www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/store
- Kazakhstan (KK-KZ) Store: www.windowsphone.com/kk-kz/store

Please excuse the lack of links on these - I am new to the WP stack exchange, and do not have the 10 reputation required to post more than 2 links. You'll have to copy+paste these into your browser.